# many to many relationship in django database model

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi I am completely new to python and implementing ORM for first time in mysql.

we have three two tables and one intermediary table as shown in below diagram
[image: many to many relationship]

below is the code we are using to create models

```
class Roles(models.Model):
    """
    A class that stores all the types of roles that are available to the user
    """
    role_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False,primary_key=True)
    role_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'roles'
        managed = False


class User(AbstractBaseUser):
# class ChannelUser(models.Model):
    """
    An abstract base class implementing a fully featured User model with
    admin-compliant permissions.

    """
    user_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=False,primary_key=True)
    user_email = models.EmailField(max_length=200, blank=False, unique=True)
    roles=models.ManyToManyField(
        Roles,
        through='UserRole',
        # through_fields=('user_id', 'role_id'),
    )

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user_email'

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user'
        managed = False

class UserRole(models.Model):
    """
    A class that stores user ids and role ids
    """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='user_id')
    role = models.ForeignKey(Roles, on_delete=models.PROTECT, db_column='role_id') 
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)   

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'user_roles'
        managed = False
```

We are trying to fetch all the `Roles` associated with `User`, but it gives None for `roles`.

I am not sure, what we are doing wrong here. can somebody please point it out.

Below is the code I am using to fetch roles

```
user_detail = User.objects.get(user_email=username)
print(user_detail.user_email)  //prints user email
print(user_detail.roles) // prints Roles.None
```

**settings.py**

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "login_api.User"
```

Comment: You need to show the code you used to fetch the roles.

Comment: what is your code ?

Comment: @DanielRoseman  Please have a look, I have updated the code

Comment: @rakwen  Please have a look, I have updated the code

Comment: There is no way that would print None. It would print "ManyRelatedManager" because roles is a many-to-many field giving you access to a queryset of related roles

Comment: but it is printing **Roles.None**

Answer (score 0):

When accessing a specific model instance (and not the model's manager) you access related items with `modelname_set` instead of `modelname`. For example:

```
>>> user_detail.roles_set.remove(my_role)
>>> user_detail.roles_set.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Docs:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/

Comment: I am facing the given error when tried your approach **print(user_details.roles_set.all())
AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'roles_set'**

Comment: I guess the obvious question is, have roles been assigned to every user? Also, have you done db migrations?

Comment: yup, I have done already used these command **python manage.py makemigrations** and **python manage.py migrate**. There is only one user in DB as of now and Roles entry for that user is present

Comment: What is your AUTH_USER_MODEL set to in your settings.py? If you add another field to User, migrate it, can you access that?

Comment: have updated the question and yes I am able to access any new additional field